# Earth Science | Chemistry + Flags

Tags: knowledge, cipher, science, flags, chemistry

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #48: Unusual tag mix](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/fortnightly-topic-challenge-48-unusual-tag-mix)</sup>

---

Which famous chemist is represented by these flags? Go big or go home!

| [image: flag 1] | [image: flag 2] | [image: flag 3] | [image: flag 4] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: flag 5] | [image: flag 6] | [image: flag 7] | [image: flag 8] |

Comment: I can add image transcriptions to the flags for those who could use it, but that might make the puzzle too easy. Also, for puzzles like these, is it better to upload the separate images, or to combine them into one bigger image?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is

> RUTHERFORD

The flags are

> Argentina, Seychelles, Canada, Austria.
>  Arkansas, Saint Pierre and Miquelon, Solomon Islands, P&O

These have the two letter codes

> AR, SC, CA, AT.
>  AR, PM, SB, PO.

These correspond to atomic symbols for

> Argon, Scandium, Calcium, Astatine,
>  Argon, Promethium, Antimony, Polonium.

Which have atomic numbers

> 18, 21, 20, 85, 18, 61, 51, 84.
>  These numbers don't quite correspond to letters of the alphabet but we can look at it as representing a sequence of digits which can be split up in an alternative way as follows,
>  18, 21, 20, 8, 5, 18, 6, 15, 18, 4.
>  This spells RUTHERFORD (where each number represents the position in the alphabet of the corresponding letter).

Comment: "Go big or go home" meant rot13(gnxr gur ynetrfg ahzore cbffvoyr gung fgvyy zncf gb n yrggre bs gur nycunorg gb fbyir gur ahzore pvcure), but I figured it wasn't super necessary.